# Import existing Class diagram and generate JPA entities

Tags: jpa, eclipse-plugin, open-source, class-diagram, rational-rsa

I have a **class diagram which is created using IBM-RSA**(3 years ago. License is over). I have **to generate JPA entities out the class diagram**. Is there any open-source tool or an eclipse Plugin which helps in generating the JPA entities.
I have explored on eclipse plugins but none of them have an option to import existing class diagram.
It would be great If anyone can suggest the tool or plugin which can help me?

Class diagram looks like 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have database tables, you can generate Java JPA entities.

To do so:-

Right click on project -> Jpa Tools -> Generate Entities from Table